# using Laravel array data in Alpine x-data directive

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a Laravel array that I want to use in an Alpine.js component:

```
 $array = Names::get('name')->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

this stores the following data and sends it to the view:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "Foo" [1]=> string(3) "Bar" [2]=> string(3) "Baz" }
```

my alpine component has the directive x-data (I am using the search example from the Getting Started page):

```
 x-data="{
    search: '',

    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],

    get filteredItems() {
        return this.items.filter(
            i => i.startsWith(this.search)
        )
    }
}"
```

I need to insert the data from $array to the x-data directive like this:

```
items: $array
```

however this is not displaying the data

I can't use the blade {{ }} as that will not echo an array

Comment: Are you displaying the data as  table?

Comment: the html from the working example used in the Alpine docs looks like this:   

<ul>
        <template x-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item">
            <li x-text="item"></li>
        </template>
    </ul>

Answer (score 2):

Use @json() directive in blade. So your alpine component should look something like:

```
x-data="{
    search: '',

    items: @json($array),

    get filteredItems() {
        return this.items.filter(
            i => i.startsWith(this.search)
        )
    }
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using livewire, you can always use alpine's entangle
It accepts arrays

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#sharing-state